# Calculation of Einstein coefficient for spontaneous emission

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, perturbation-theory

I want to calculate the rate of spontaneous emission for the transition: $|3,2,2\rangle$ to $|2,1,1\rangle$ in a hydrogen atom.

Corresponding to the formula of $A_{ab}$ the only thing to derive is the matrix element $|\langle \psi_{211} | \boldsymbol r | \psi_{322} \rangle|^2$, where **r** is the position vector in spherical coordinates.

But when I plug all this into Mathematica, it gives me $0$ as the answer. This seems contra intuitive to me since the transition is likely to happen due to transition rules.

I get: $\langle \psi_{211} | \boldsymbol r | \psi_{322} \rangle=\frac{16588}{78125}a_0 \boldsymbol e_x-\frac{16588}{78125}ia_0\boldsymbol e_y+0\boldsymbol e_z$ and absolute square of this is obviously $0$.

My calculations:

For x-component:[image]

For y-component:  [image]

For z-component: [image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There might be en error in your code...

Comment: So the idea behind the calculation should be correct, right?

Comment: Or have I missed something about Polarisation? But actually we don't need to consider because in a spontaneous emission there is no external field...

Comment: Your question is not clear: I suppose there is an equation that you plug into Mathematica in order to perform the calculation. From your question one cannot know neither the equation you use, nor how it is coded in Mathematica - so it is impossible to say whether there is an error, and if there is a conceptual error (which could make it a legitimate question here; but note that homework questions are generally against Physics SE policy.)

Comment: I have added now the codes from Mathematica, I am really sorry this not a homework question, I am self studying atomic physics and I came across this problem without a solution and it confuses me a lot...

Comment: It is still not clear where Mathematica gives you the zero answer that you do not agree with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146531/discussion-between-blue2001-and-roger-vadim).

Comment: The magnitude squared of the matrix element as you stated it is not zero. X and Y component do not cancel each other. I think you should make another attempt at calculating the magnitude square, writing out the scalar product and the complex conjugation. Here is a little hint $|-i|^2=1$

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This solved everything, now it makes sense!! How could I miss that...

Comment: I recommend that you write an answer to your own question, addressing the mistake made and showing the correct calculation. You can then accept your answer, which makes it clear that the problem is resolved. Otherwise people might continue to browse this question, although it is resolved.

Comment: I don’t understand why $\psi_{322}$ has a $e^{-2i\varphi}$ rather than a $e^{2i\varphi}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was found by the user „Hans Wurst“.

$\langle \psi_{211} | \boldsymbol r | \psi_{322} \rangle=\frac{16588}{78125}a_0 \boldsymbol e_x-\frac{16588}{78125}ia_0\boldsymbol e_y+0\boldsymbol e_z$ is also right but the absolute square of this is not zero as I thought, since it is complex, so in summary we get:

$|\langle \psi_{211} | \boldsymbol r | \psi_{322} \rangle|=\sqrt2\frac{16588}{78125}a_0$